# Numpy fast conditional index operation

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose you have 3D array.
What would be the fastest method to perform the following operation for large arrays:

```
If:
i_low < i < i_high and
j_low < j < j_high and
k_low < k < k_high

Then:
change the element value to 1
```

Answer (score 2):

One relatively fast way would be to use NumPy's slicing:

```
a[i_low+1:i_high, j_low+1:j_high, k_low+1:k_high] = 1
```